# Combos en el layout, con Razor .NET

Tags: .net, razor, layout

Buen día, tengo que añadir al _layout.cshtml 2 combos que se encuentren siempre visible, por más que cambie de controller o de vista, soy nuevo en .NET y quería saber como puedo hacer esto. Los combos se generan a partir de una consulta en la base de datos.
Estoy utilizando .NET, MVC 4 y Razor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde ya muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Saludos.

Comment: Podrías seccionar el layout (`Header.cshtml, LeftSide.html`, etc) o simplemente crear los combos en el body (antes de `RenderBody` por supuesto).

Comment: Claro, a lo que voy... es tengo que crear un controller base que implemente los combos dependientes y que de esta manera se muestren en todas las vistas.?